# Cannot import jdl file using jhipster

Tags: import, jhipster, jdl

I'm new to jhipster. I am on jhipster v7.8.1, i can generate an app using the cli questions but when i try importing a jdl file i got the following error:

**ERROR! Class constructor GAstVisitor cannot be invoked without 'new'
TypeError: Class constructor GAstVisitor cannot be invoked without 'new'
at new DslMethodsCollectorVisitor

Comment: Please try latest version 7.9.2

Comment: Have upgraded to v7.9.2 recently, also upgraded node.js to v16.17.0. The error raised when I try to update entities with jdl, throws: ERROR! Class constructor GAstVisitor cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: even when i upgraded the version still not working

Comment: I have reproduced it. This is a blocking bug in the JDL parser, I have opened an issue https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/19486

Answer (score 2):

This occurs due to a recent bug in the one of JHipster libraries. As a temporary solution you can go to the JHipster installed location and find it's package.json file and override the package causing this error as follows. Then run npm install again.

```
    "overrides":{
      "chevrotain@10.1.2": {
      "@chevrotain/gast": "10.1.2"
     }
    }
```

This will prevent the JHipster using latest package of that.

Comment: in the package.json, i find this:  "dependencies": {"@faker-js/faker": "5.5.3","aws-sdk":"2.1106.0","axios": "0.26.1","chalk": "4.1.2","chevrotain": "10.1.2","commander": "9.1.0",.......}  but no "overrides" .....

Comment: From what he said, this is the package.json of the generator, so it should be node_modules\generator-jhipster\package.json in your project. I did not test it though.

Comment: I added these lines in the file but same issue, how should I add them correctly?

Comment: yeah , i did find the right file, but it has already the dependency cherveotain with the version 10.1.2

Comment: @kk99 the problem is with the @chevrotain/gast dependency not chevrotain itself.  So after adding the overrides section to the package.json of the generator-jhipster, remove it's node_modules directory and package-lock.json file. Then run npm install within the generator-jhipster directory

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same error and managed to get the JDL file to run by using **version 7.8.1**
I followed the following steps to get this done;

1. uninstall the current version of jhipster that is causing issues for
   my case this was 7.9.2 . use this command **npm uninstall -g
   generator-jhipster**
2. Install version 7.8.1 using this command **npm
   install -g generator-jhipster@7.8.1**
3. Attempt to run your JDL using
   this command **jhipster jdl jhipster-jdl.jdl**
4. At this stage, your JDL
   will be able to run